# Evaluate $\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}(-i,3)}\frac{\sin(z)}{(z-3)^3}\, \mathrm{\mathop{d}}z$ using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

I would like to evaluate
$$\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}(-i,3)}\frac{\sin(z)}{(z-3)^3}\mathrm{\mathop{d}}z$$

using Cauchy's Integral Formula.

**Notation**: We denote $\partial \mathbb{B}(a, R)$ to be the boundary of the ball $\mathbb{B}(a, R)$. In this question, it will be the circle p radius $R$, centre $a$.

The Cauchy Integral Formula that I am working with says:

> Suppose that $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and $z_0 \in E$. Pick $\rho > 0$ such that $\overline{\mathbb{B}(z_0, \rho)} \in E$. Let $C \subset E$ be a closed curve such that $\exists$ region $\Omega \subset E \setminus \{z_0\}$ such that $\partial \Omega = C \cup (-\partial \mathbb{B} (z_0, \rho))$. Then $f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,\mathop{\mathrm{d}}z$ (integral is oriented counterclockwise but I can't get the $\LaTeX$ code \ointctrclockwise to work).

The answer says that the integral evaluates to $-\pi i \sin (2i)$ and it uses $f(z) = \sin (z)$, $z_0 = 2i$, and differentiates $f(z_0)$ twice.

I understand that I cannot choose the curve $C$ to be $\mathbb{B}(-i,3)$ AND choose $z_0 = 3$ since then $z_0 \notin C$ and we canot satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem. Then how do we choose $z_0$?

Comment: See if there is a theorem nearby that one where the denominator is a power of the $(z-z_0)$ ...

Comment: @GEdgar This seems to be obtained by differentiating twice, but I still don't understand how $z_0$ is chosen. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably you have copied the problem incorrectly.  I think the integral you actually wrote has value zero, since the integrand is analytic on the whole disk $B(-i,3)$.

Comment: @GEdgar I understand that we have holomorphicity on the whole disk, but $z_0 = 3$, the obvious choice, doesn't lie in this disk. I want to know why the answer has chosen $z_0 = 2i$, which does lie in the closed disk but doesn't seem correspond to the question.

Comment: It would perhaps be good to write down *specifically* what you mean by some not-so-standard symbols. For example, is $\;\partial\Bbb B(-i,3)\;$ a circle of radius $\;3\;$ and center at $\;-i\;$ ? As far as I know that is the boundary of something but I'm not that sure of what.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I'll edit that into the question for clarity.

Comment: What you say about $\;2i\;$ and etc. fits for $\;\frac{\sin z}{(z-2i)^3}\;$, *not* for the function you wrote. You'd also need a larger radius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say about what the answer says and etc. doesn't seem to make much sense, since

$$|3+i|=\sqrt{3^3+1^2}=\sqrt{10}>3\implies\;f(z):=\frac{\sin z}{(z-3)^n}$$

is analytic on $\;|z+i|=3\;$ and in its interior and thus by CIT we get the integral equals zero.

I can't see what $\;z_0=2i\;$ has to do with all this...

Comment: Following on from your comment, with the function that you suggested, should the answer perhaps be $\pi i \sin (2i)$ instead? I also can't see where a minus sign would come from.

Comment: If the radius is slightly larger than $\;3\;$ so that $\;2i\;$ **not** on the integration path, then indeed $$\oint_C\frac{\sin z}{(z-2i)^3}dz=\left.\frac{2\pi i}{2!}\left(\sin z\right)''\right|_{z=2i}=-\pi i\sin(2i)$$

Comment: Thanks, I see that the minus sign comes from differentiating twice. How can we choose $f(z)$ to be as you have done? I can't see where it fits into the formula.

Comment: I seem to have misread CIT as CIF, I now realise that Cauchy's Theorem has been used, thanks for the help!